# Laravel Valet Share URL Leads to connection refused

Tags: ngrok, laravel-valet

Been trying to share the local site using a temporary url https://xxxxx.ngrok.io running with Laravel Valet. When I run Valet version 1.1.22:

```
valet --version
Laravel Valet version 1.1.22
```

securely the ngrok url leads to a connection refused. When it is unsecure it leads to connection refused as well (404 only with valet running on the secondary machine as it wouldn't be found there). Either that or a DNS resolving issue as I mention later on.

Locally on my wifi network and on the PC is works just fine. Access logs show me this:

```
127.0.0.1 - [03/Oct/2016:08:57:06 +0300] "POST /server.php?doing_wp_cron=1475474226.5450510978698730468750 HTTP/1.1" 200 0
127.0.0.1 - [03/Oct/2016:08:57:07 +0300] "POST /server.php HTTP/1.1" 200 47
127.0.0.1 - [03/Oct/2016:08:59:09 +0300] "POST /server.php?doing_wp_cron=1475474348.8563120365142822265625 HTTP/1.1" 200 0
127.0.0.1 - [03/Oct/2016:08:59:10 +0300] "POST /server.php HTTP/1.1" 200 47
```

Still do not see an error related to refused connection in this log at ~/.valet/Log/access.log . Error logs show old errors, not related to this issue. Ngrook window in terminal shows 301 Moved permanently on the two loads I just tried. Ngrok status site http://localhost:4040/status showed me:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: site.dev
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/601.7.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.3 Safari/601.7.8
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-us
X-Forwarded-For: xx.xx.xx.xxx
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Original-Host: xxxxxx.ngrok.io
```

and then the redirect:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://mysite.dev/
Server: Caddy
Status: 301 Moved Permanently
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.11
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=edge
Date: Mon, 03 Oct 2016 06:14:10 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Caddyfile here for completion (generated by Valet):

```
import /Users/jasper/.valet/Caddy/*

    :80 {
        fastcgi / 127.0.0.1:9000 php {
            index server.php
        }

        rewrite {
            to /server.php?{query}
        }

        log /Users/jasper/.valet/Log/access.log {
            rotate {
                size 10
                age 3
                keep 1
            }
        }

        errors {
            log /Users/jasper/.valet/Log/error.log {
                size 10
                age 3
                keep 1
             }
        }
    }
```

[Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) is running too (added after tld domain was changed to .localhost):

```
ps aux | grep ngrok
jasper           1260   0.0  0.2 556735952  28692 s001  S+   10:23AM   1:27.14 /Users/jasper/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/bin/ngrok http -host-header=rewrite site.localhost:80
root             1254   0.0  0.1  2463108   8964 s001  S+   10:23AM   0:00.01 sudo -u jasper /Users/jasper/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/bin/ngrok http -host-header=rewrite site.localhost:80
jasper           3557   0.0  0.0  2432804   2096 s000  S+    2:36PM   0:00.00 grep ngrok
```

So it does hit the Caddy Server and the ngrok status does show that. But it then does a redirect which translates into a connection refused or DNS resolution problemns for the browsers.. So what is the issue here?

Comment: Did a `valet domain localhost` as recommended at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719851/pinging-test-dev-after-laravel-valet-install-returns-unknown-host#37730896 and restarted all as I got worried about TLD name collision. But, no, that was not the issue..

Comment: Also Safari sometimes tells me `Tunnel www.xxxx.ngrok.io not found` now. Chrome still shows connection refused.

Comment: Latest error in iOS Chrome is that DNS address could not be found. And it does not even seem to hit the site locally now as no Ngrok log entry appears.

Comment: Do get Ngrok entries. Still DNS errors in the browser. No more connection refused. Issue with 301 redirect is likely causing all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I realized WordPress was creating an extra redirect using its permalink structure. So when you turn off permalinks you can share your Laravel Valet WordPress site to the outside world using Ngrok. Not the perfect solution, but at least one that works and that allows you to show your work in progress to clients running it on your local machine.