# Laravel and Valet bizarre loading issue

Tags: laravel

Strange problem: Have installed Laravels 'Valet' to serve sites from .dev locally. When I am in my 'code' directory where I parked valet and create say `laravel new blog` installed perfectly and spins up on blog.dev. However say I create `laravel new test` and visit test.dev I get `404 - nothing found` ...? I removed everything and tried again but the same thing happens. Has anyone else had the same problem?

**UPDATE**

Interestingly, from that same directory 'code' If i run a ping on blog.dev I get returned packets and pings. However I do the same on test, I get bunch of help commands?

**FURTHER UPDATE**

So inside the project 'test' if I run `php artisan serve` I get a response of `Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>` and If I visit the path bingo it works. But that confuses the issue even further for me...?

**EVEN FUTHER UPDATES**

So, I wish to add this iMac was a previous developers so the home folder is called Adam, I am a seperate user but also an Admin with my own folder sat next to it called 'Dan'but not a 'home' directory as such it is just in the sames 'Users' directory whenever I try to do anything I get errors like: `ERROR:  Notice: Undefined index: domain in /Users/Adam/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/cli/valet.php on line 55` That was when trying to spin up `laravel share`

Comment: comment on the 'further update' . php artisan serve works indepently from valet, so that has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: @Christophvh I 100% understand that. But I wanted to share what I was doing to try and remedy the issue so people have a fuller understanding. Less Questions.

Comment: ok, because you statet that confused you. Maybe you can try to restart your brew services? `sudo brew services start --all`  Also this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719851/pinging-test-dev-after-laravel-valet-install-returns-unknown-host

Comment: @Christophvh No problem. Hmm that is strange. I get an error: `Error: Failure while executing: /bin/launchctl bootstrap system /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist` - Re the suggested thread, kinda loosely based on my question but not very relatable. I will add to my question also

Comment: That error says that there is a problem with your dnsmasq . Which is exactly what the thread accepted answers suggests: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37730896/3493752

Comment: That was for when I was trying to Laravel share, the issue im having is that I cna only load blog.dev and no other projects...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144068/discussion-between-danjbh-and-christophvh).

Comment: Further to my issue something strange has happened, I can now ping both blog.dev and test.dev and get a response... Still no valet working though.