# Laravel valet It works

Tags: laravel, laravel-valet

I'm trying to install `Laravel valet` but I keep getting (when I visit domain.dev):

```
It works!
```

I already tried a lot. For example:

```
remove valet 
stop apache (apachectl stop)
composer global require laravel/valet
valet install
valet restart
```

But that does not work for me. I've also installed `Laravel Homestead`  in a vagrant box. Perhaps that has something to do with it? I can visit my Homestead sites.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: "It works!" is the standard Apache page on OSX. You need to ensure you stop Apache running.

Comment: If I exec `sudo apachectl -k stop` I receive the same message -_-

Comment: Have a look at another answer I posted about this. It covers most points RE valet http://stackoverflow.com/a/37174256/769237 and might sort your issue. Having worked through that, let me know and I'll suggest other options

Comment: Not working for me!

Comment: What doesn't work? `sudo lsof -n -i:80 | grep LISTEN` will tell you what is listening on port 80. If you're still seeing "It works!", it's probably still Apache so you'll need to ensure that's stopped.

Comment: @Jamie Try choosing an answer as correct if one of the answers below fixed your problem.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

"It works!" will always be a message from Apache.
Apache has to be turned off for Laravel Valet to work.

I see you have tried these before:

- `$ stop apache (apachectl stop)`
- `$ sudo apachectl -k stop`

I had the same problem. Try with the command below and then after be sure to restart valet again! **This fixed it for me**:

```
$ sudo apachectl stop
$ valet restart
```

Answer (score 6):

So many different combinations of what to do here

Here is what worked for me.

Turn off other local Apache altogether

```
sudo apachectl -k stop

sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

Remove the Valet directory altogether

```
rm -r ~/.valet
```

Removed Valet via composer globally

```
composer global remove laravel/valet
```

Re-install via composer

```
composer global require laravel/valet
```

Install Valet

```
valet install
```

Go to Folder to Add directories

```
cd ~/Sites/
```

Then add projects to park

```
valet park
```

Change Valet domains to something else to stop urls forcing to https://

```
valet domain app
```

Change directory into the project folder

```
cd ./laravel-project/
```

Then open current project

```
valet open
```

The browser should open to http://laravel-project.app

Answer (score -3):

No need to stop Apache, and it doesn't have anything to do with Homestead.

The answers provided solve your problem but they are not good.

You can simply run

```
valet port 8888
```

(or whatever port you want) and get your site on domain.dev:8888

The point is not that Apache and Nginx don't like each other, they are agnostic of each other, just keep them listening on different ports.