# Valet installed for laravel, but why isn't dnsmasq resolving correctly?

Tags: laravel, homebrew, dnsmasq, laravel-valet, php-7.3

I've installed valet for laravel using homebrew on my mac (Mojave). According to [laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/valet#valet-or-homestead) I should now be able to ping *.test, but when I keep getting the following error:

> ping:cannot resolve foobar.test: Unknown host

It looks like an issue with dnsmasq. I've followed all the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37174256/472377), but nothing seems to help.

```
# Content of '/Users/<username>/.config/valet/dnsmasq.conf'

address=/.test/127.0.0.1
listen-address=127.0.0.1
```

I can see that the resolver for .test seems to be set up ok. Below is the output from `scutil --dns`

```
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : default
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.1.1
  if_index : 6 (en0)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)

resolver #2
  domain   : local
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300000

resolver #3
  domain   : 254.169.in-addr.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300200

resolver #4
  domain   : 8.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300400

resolver #5
  domain   : 9.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300600

resolver #6
  domain   : a.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300800

resolver #7
  domain   : b.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 301000

resolver #8
  domain   : test
  nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00030002 (Reachable,Local Address,Directly Reachable Address)

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : default
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.1.1
  if_index : 6 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)
```

I can also see that dnsmasq seems to be running ok. Here's the output from `brew services list`:

```
dnsmasq started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
httpd   started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist
mysql   started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
nginx   started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
php     started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
php@7.1 started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php@7.1.plist
php@7.2 started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php@7.2.plist
```

Other things I've tried:

- Disabling my firewall in case that was blocking the request.
- Restarting dnsmasq (multiple times) using: `sudo brew services
  restart dnsmasq`
- Reinstalling valet using `valet install`
- Checking that there are no conflicting paths in /etc/hosts

Anyone got any other suggestions?

EDIT: Output of `sudo brew services restart --verbose dnsmasq`

```
`Stopping `dnsmasq`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `dnsmasq` (label: homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq)
==> Generated plist for dnsmasq:
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
     <dict>
       <key>Label</key>
       <string>homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq</string>
       <key>ProgramArguments</key>
       <array>
         <string>/usr/local/opt/dnsmasq/sbin/dnsmasq</string>
         <string>--keep-in-foreground</string>
         <string>-C</string>
         <string>/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf</string>
       </array>
       <key>RunAtLoad</key>
       <true/>
       <key>KeepAlive</key>
       <true/>
     </dict>
   </plist>


/bin/launchctl enable system/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq
/bin/launchctl bootstrap system /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
==> Successfully started `dnsmasq` (label: homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq)
```

EDIT 2:

I think I'm getting somewhere now. I checked in console.app for dnsmasq and I saw the error message:

`failed to open pidfile /usr/local/var/run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid: No such file or directory`

...which led me [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services/issues/164). It turns out I was missing the `dnsmasq` folder in `cd /usr/local/var/run/` so I ran `sudo mkdir dnsmasq` and now the ping actually returns the following response:

```
PING foobar.test (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
...
```

I'm not sure what this means or whether it is now working.

When I go to foobar.test in my browser I get the message `This site can’t be reached` even though I have created a project with that name and linked it using `valet link foobar`.

EDIT 3:

I've got ping working properly now by turning off stealth mode (as described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/100005/65294)) but I still get `This site can’t be reached` when I navigate to foobar.test in my browser.

I get the following error when I run `curl foobar.test --verbose`

```
* Rebuilt URL to: foobar.test/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to foobar.test (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: foobar.test
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

EDIT 4

Output of `cat /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf | grep -i interface`:

```
# 10.1.2.3 to 192.168.1.1 port 55 (there must be an interface with that
# specified interfaces (and the loopback) give the name of the
# interface (eg eth0) here.
# Repeat the line for more than one interface.
#interface=
# Or you can specify which interface _not_ to listen on
#except-interface=
# If you want dnsmasq to provide only DNS service on an interface,
#no-dhcp-interface=
# even when it is listening on only some interfaces. It then discards
# working even when interfaces come and go and change address. If you
# want dnsmasq to really bind only the interfaces it is listening on,
#bind-interfaces
# that these two Ethernet interfaces will never be in use at the same
# Always give the InfiniBand interface with hardware address
```

Comment: but do you have a foobar.test site working in your machine?

Comment: No, but according to [laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/valet#valet-or-homestead) I don't need one. `"Once Valet is installed, try pinging any *.test domain on your terminal using a command such as ping foobar.test. If Valet is installed correctly you should see this domain responding on 127.0.0.1."`

Comment: Can you validate that your `$ valet domain` indeed is `test`? It's configurable. There might be some older config residing in `~/.config/valet`

Comment: @Tom Yes, when I run `valet domain` it returns 'test'.

Comment: @Urbycoz have you parked Valet in a specific folder? For example `~/Code/` what this does is then sets every folder inside that one as a domain,  so `~/Code/myproject` becomes accessible at http://myproject.test there's some info [here for you to take a look at](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/valet#the-park-command).

Comment: @swonder Yes I did `cd /Users/urbycoz/development/php-valet` then `valet park`

Comment: Try `valet restart` or restarting your computer, something may have just gone a bit skew-iff.

Comment: @swonder I've restarted the mac and done `valet restart` but still the same.

Comment: @ChinLeung That's the whole of it.

Comment: You sir, have just resolved over 8 hours of troubleshooting. Creating the dnsmasq folder worked.

Answer (score 4):

Dnsmasq can break when you have a VPN active.

Comment: This is precisely what was happening to me and I couldn't figure out why. I needed to restart the dnsmasq after each time I would start my vpn, even after ending the connection.

Answer (score 2):

Please verify that you have a `/etc/resolver/test` file containing this row: `nameserver 127.0.0.1`

Also, edit your `/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf` file by uncommenting and changing this line:

```
#interface=
```

to this:

```
interface=lo0
```

Then restart the service again with `sudo brew services restart dnsmasq` and try again.

The idea is that during the installation the `dnsmasq` daemon might have got bound to some interface which is not available anymore.
By changing it to `lo0` you would force it to only serve your loopback interface which is always present. And I guess you won't need it operating on any of your external-facing interfaces as I guess that's all for development purposes. Yet if you do, you could add more interface rows like this:

```
interface=lo0
interface=en0
```

Comment: Yes I do have that file and it contains that text.

Comment: Could you please check the output of:
`ps aux | grep dnsmasq`
you should have a line looking like this:
`usr/local/opt/dnsmasq/sbin/dnsmasq --keep-in-foreground -C /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf`
We're interested in the config file path in this line (in my case that's `/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf`).
Then do `cat /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf | grep "conf-file"` and please provide the output.

Comment: I don't see a line like that when I run `ps aux | grep dnsmasq`. All I see is 1 line saying `urbycoz       1394   0.0  0.0  4267932    344 s000  R+   11:32am   0:00.00 grep dnsmasq`

Comment: This is the output when I run `cat /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf | grep "conf-file"`: `#conf-file=/etc/dnsmasq.more.conf
conf-file=/Users/urbycoz/.config/valet/dnsmasq.conf`

Comment: That's a problem if you're not seeing a `dnsmasq` proccess via `ps aux | grep dnsmasq`.
Could give us the output of `sudo brew services restart --verbose dnsmasq`

Comment: OK, lets try these then. What's the output of `sudo lsof -i:53 -P -n` and also `cat /var/log/system.log | grep -i dnsmasq`

Comment: The output of `sudo lsof -i:53 -P -n` is nothing. When I run `/var/log/system.log | grep -i dnsmasq` I get: `May 24 10:16:11 Urbycozs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq[18157]): Service exited with abnormal code: 2
May 24 10:16:11 Urbycozs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds` repeated about 50 times.

Comment: The `dnsmasq` service seems to not be able to start at all. Try reloading the service like this:
`sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist && sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist` and try again.

Comment: Ok I've run those, but it didn't help.

Comment: I have anothеr hunch. Give us the output of: `cat /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf | grep -i interface`.

Comment: Ok I've added the output to the question.

Comment: I've updated the answer with proposed changes to `/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, please try this and I hope it works.

Comment: I've followed your instructions but I'm afraid it's still not working.

Comment: Did you check `cat /var/log/system.log | grep -i dnsmasq`? Do you still keep getting the `... Service exited with abnormal code: 2 ...` errors, or is there another error message?

Comment: Same message I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Forticlient installed, it can break dnsmasq.

The workaround is either:

- Add the entries manually to your `/etc/hosts` file: `127.0.0.1 localhost dirname1.test dirname2.test`
- Disable the Forticlient launch daemons/agents by deleting or moving all `com.fortinet.forticlient.*` entries in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` and `/Library/LaunchAgents`, then restart your mac

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that at the bottom of your `dnsmasq.conf` has the following line pointing to your Valet config:

```
conf-file=/Users/urbycoz/.config/valet/dnsmasq.conf
```

Comment: This line already exists in `/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, but not in `/Users/urbycoz/.config/valet/dnsmasq.conf`

Comment: @Urbycoz Can you show what's inside your `/Users/urbycoz/.config/valet/dnsmasq.conf`?

Comment: This is the content: `address=/.test/127.0.0.1
listen-address=127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo /usr/local/sbin/dnsmasq --no-daemon --log-queries
```

which will start dnsmask without detaching from the console and will give you what error is preventing the dnsmasq to start.

In my case, it was

```
dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 127.0.0.1: Address already in use
```

So I restarted my PC. Then I did `valet start`. Now the dnsmasq is working.